# How to Install Satchmo in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, django, windows-vista, satchmo

I'm working on a Django project that's slated to be using Satchmo for its e-commerce aspects.  I'd like to install it on my Windows Vista machine but some of the cPython modules it needs can't be compiled or easy_installed.

Has anyone been able to get Satchmo working on Windows, and if so, what additional steps does it take over the installation instructions?

Comment: Please provide details about the failing compilations/easy_installs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which modules are you having trouble with? 
Pycrypto binaries are here - http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto
Python Imaging binaries are here - http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

I believe everything else is pure python so it should be pretty simple to install the rest.